# Permission Issues for User 1

Tags: views, users, panels

I have added pages, webform, and views to my site to customize the User profile experience. I can access mysite.org/user and it shows my user profile page as customized. I have a link on that page to Edit the user profile which is formatted as mysite.org/user/1/edit this works fine. I also have realname module installed so the Edit button on the User profile tabs has the url mysite.org/user/my-real-name/edit This link does not work. It gives an access denied when used even from the User 1 account. I have researched this over and over and over. I can't find the cause or the fix. Any ideas?

I've checked permissions, I've gone through the panel page, the view. I've disabled things and tried it and still issues. I'm at a total loss on what to do.

Comment: are you sure a url alias is being assigned using the real-name parameter?

Comment: Yes, Just checked it.

Comment: assuming you have customised the edit via panels, have you tried disabling panels entirely for that page?

Comment: I didn't customize the edit via panels. The only thing I did to the Edit was created a webform which I then used Views to create a page which rendered the webform at user/%/edit/My_Details

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [Real Name](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname) does what you think it does.  At least not by default.  The module is primarily for using parts of the user account other than the username when the user account is displayed (such as the by-line on an article).

You can set the edit link to send people to `mysite.org/user/my-real-name/edit` but unless you've done something to make that URL exist, which I'm not sure you can do with this module, it won't do anything.

Comment: Then why does `mysite.org/user/my-real-name` work? I also have [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) as well as subpathauto so this should take care of creating those links

Comment: it follows the same idea that you can go to a url alias of:  /this-is-the-node-title, but by default, the edit page would be: node/12/edit - unless there is something specifically overriding that default behaviour

Comment: Geoff is right, just because `user/%` has an alias, it doesn't mean that `user/%/edit` will have a similar alias.

Comment: Although it appears subPathAuto should handle that, I would look in the settings for that module.

Comment: The subpathauto module is set to 3 depth and it works on other content with the /edit argument. It's just not working on the user node.

Comment: Perhaps SubPathAuto has a bug, or it is something to do with the known issue listed on the project page. I suggest checking the issue queue if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the Real Names module.
There are 2 Types of links in Drupal:

- system links like **/user/1** or **/node/240**
- and alias links like **/user/johndoe** or **/content/about** (they point to system links and are generated by modules like Pathauto)

While most of the site is accessible via alias links generated by pathauto, certain admin links require arguments on the system link: **/content/about/edit** does not work – **/node/240/edit** is the correct link, because there is no alias for the edit link.

Same with the user page: You can't mix system links (accepting special arguments like **/edit**) with path aliases. The only way to do that would be to generate a separate alias for all argument links (e.g. an alias for **/node/240/edit**, **/node/240/delete**) – some sites actuallay do that, via Rules for example.

Comment: That's why I have the module [subpathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) installed. It does this all links.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's not very common – you should mention this in your original post.